# JTextPane StyleConstants double spacing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextpane

I am trying to get my java application to add a double spacing feature, using
StyleDocs and StyleConstants. So far this is what I have.

```
   void doSpace(){

   StyleConstants.setLineSpacing(style, 5);

    try { doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), " ",style); }
    catch (BadLocationException r){}
    }
```

I apply this and nothing happens.
I believe my error is in the `doc.insertString`
However this has worked when trying to change the font size, and color.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

When you just insert the text with style (AttributeSet) it is applied to text (character) element (leaves).

To apply line spacing call

```
yourStyledDocument.setParagraphAttributes(..., yourStyleWithLineSpacing);
```

This way the line spacing will be applied to paragraph.